# Query to calculate money sent By Customer and total orders placed by him

Tags: mysql

I've Northwind sample database. It has 8 tables(`Customers`,`Categories`,`Employees`,`OrderDetails`,`Orders`,`Products`, `Shipper` and `Suppliers`) I'm Applying Query which calculate the total orders place by the each Customer and money spent by him till now. Query is here:

```
select c.CustomerID,
       SUM(p.Price*od.Quantity) as Totalspent,
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrder
from Orders o LEFT join Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    join [OrderDetails] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    join Products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
group by c.CustomerID order by    c.customerid
```

But It's not calculating the totalOrders correctly. I'm extracting data From 4 tables `Orders`, `Customers`,`OrderDetails` and `Products`. check the following link for tables.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: Please edit your question with proper indentation

Comment: Please show us current output and also what is expected.  And sample data would be nice too.  I can't see anything wrong right now.

Comment: This sql does not look like a MySQL one, it is either for MS Access or MS SQL Server. Northwind is also an MS supplied sample database.